# Converting webGL html to SVG

Tags: r, svg, latex, webgl, vector-graphics

I am using R, with the misc3d and rpanel libraries, to create a 3d image in webGL. I then need to embed the image into a PDF via Latex.

The 3d image renders fine and looks great - but I'm thinking I need to convert the webGL HTML file into an SVG or some other kind of vector graphics file which *can* be embedded in Latex.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am wrong but this way doesn't make sense to me.

- You have 3D coordinates
- You render objects based on 3D coordinates to a 2D rasterized image using webGL
- Then you want to extract 2D vector coordinates from the rendered image?

From the webGL framebuffer you can get the rasterized data (no vector information). So it is like converting a rasterized image (like png) to SVG. Since there is no way (I know) to get the vector information back from a rasterized image chances are high that the image will just be embedded in the SVG file. This wouldn't be a real benefit compared to a rasterized image.

Maybe you can use the vector informations (which you are using for drawing the webGL image) for drawing to a SVG image directly?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't use the `rgl` package instead (I'm not really familiar with `rpanel`, but I'm pretty sure that `misc3d` was originally design to work in conjunction with `rgl`) and use `rgl.postscript(...,fmt="pdf")` to export directly to PDF? `rgl.postscript` also offers an SVG option. The results are admittedly a little wonky sometimes (the underlying package it uses isn't completely reliable), but it's definitely the past of least resistance.

Also, I haven't tried it out myself, but I think the following article gives some information about embedding `rgl` images in their full, rotatable glory into PDFs: Levine, Richard A., Luke Tierney, Hadley Wickham, Eric Sampson, Dianne Cook, and David A. van Dyk. 2010. “Editorial: Publishing Animations, 3D Visualizations, and Movies in JCGS.” Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics 19 (1) (January): 1–2. doi:10.1198/jcgs.2010.191ed. http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jcgs.2010.191ed.

Comment: FWIW, I found a copy of (what I think is) the example PDF from that article, and couldn't get any rotation from it in Preview or Chrome's PDF viewer.

Comment: That's not surprising.  I would expect it to be viewer-specific, and very probably Adobat Reader-specific ...