# Translate 3D model to SVG programatically from various points of view

Tags: .net, svg, rendering, vector-graphics, 3d-model

Is there any way to programmatically, preferably in .NET, translate any common type of 3D models to SVGs for a given set of points-of-views (and lighting conditions)?

I found these related questions:

- [how-to-convert-3d-models-to-svg-line-art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676544/how-to-convert-3d-models-to-svg-line-art) - question and its answer are specific to Adobe PDFs.
- [converting-webgl-html-to-svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059669/converting-webgl-html-to-svg?rq=1) - specific to WebGL